# Запуск python exe приложения без вывода консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть программа написанная на python, которую я собираю в exe. Теперь мне нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы запуская её не выводилось консольное окно. Это как-то можно сделать? Я слышал, что можно что-то придумать добавив расширение к скрипту, вместо .py написать что-то другое. Но мне важно, чтобы такая программа запускалась без установленного пайтона на компьютере. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275293/hiding-console-window-of-python-gui-app-with-py2exe

Comment: А графическое есть окно?

Answer (score 1):

pyinstaller --onefile **-w** file.py

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

> без установленного пайтона на компьютере

pyinstaller не компилирует, не транслирует код питона. Грубо описать его работу можно так: копируется папка питона с нужными модулями, копируется сам проект, делается скрипт для запуска. То есть питон установлен не будет, но он на целевом компьютере будет находится в папке с твоей программой, а не по стандартному пути.

> добавив расширение к скрипту, вместо .py

Есть три стандартных расширения скриптов питона
*.pyw - запускает скрипт без открытия консоли
*.pyo - содержит прекомпилированый код, который быстрее читается интерпритатором, но не читаем для человека

> не выводилось консольное окно.

Здесь можно найти обходные пути, как то переопределение функции print, чтобы она не выводила ничего в консоль, запуск по ярлыку при `cmd -h "py main.py"`, или открытие окна за пределами видимой части монитора.